# Check if keys in TreeSet start with String, and get that key

Tags: java

I have a `TreeSet` filled with `Strings` that I want to use to see if any of the keys inside it start with a string outside the set, and be able to get that specific key and do something with it (put it in a string) For example my `String` is `test 1 2 3` and I have a `key` in the set that is `test 1 2` which should return true and tell me the key. The reason I am using a TreeSet is because I need a case-insensitive way to read the keys in my yaml file. I have used an iterator on the set before using

```
Iterator<String> itr = myTreeSet.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
if (myString.startsWith(itr.next())){ }
```

but I could not the key that made the if statement true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close... it's this line that is wrong

```
if (myString.startsWith(itr.next())){ }
```

it should be this - because the key should start with the `myString`.

```
String theKey = null;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  theKey = itr.next();
  if (theKey.startsWith(myString)) {
    return theKey;
  }
}
return null;
```

Comment: @Alex Edited to return the found key.

Answer (score 1):

Call subSet() is more proper way for tree set than iterating over it.

```
myTreeSet.subSet(str, str + "\uffff")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to get what you want:

```
Iterator<String> itr = myTreeSet.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
     String myString = itr.next()
     if (myString.startsWith(myString)){ 
         System.out.println(myString);
     }
}
```